# Merged Headers in Ext JS Grid

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is it possible to have two headers in Ext JS grids? I have to show my grid as grouped data.. for example product types and products. In my case I need a grid like this:

```
Field      |  Product Type A       |      Product Type B    |  
           --------------------------------------------------  
           |     A1   |     A1     |   B1   |   B2   |  B3  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
    T1           3          4          3        2       1   
    T2           3          8          1        5       8   
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is grid layout possible like this?

Thanks for help in advance..

Regards,
Abdel Olakara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robert,
 Thanks.. I got the plugin for grouping header.. 
[link text](https://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=250843)

Comment: You should have marked Robert's answer as the correct one then :)

Answer (score 2):

### Create a Grid Custom Plugin

Everything is possible as long as you know what to do... :) I suggest you look at creating custom plugins for existing ExtJS components.

Based on the info you've provided it's hard to tell anything because we don't know whether you know both (or maybe even more groups) header groups at the beginning? Wheter your groups are collapsible and maybe displaying sums as well...

But anyway. It is possible by either creating a plugin or a completely new extended GridPanel.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following extension: http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=76322

Something similar to this is being released as ux for Ext 3.1.